# Where to put a function to create a pdf

Tags: cakephp

I have an application which deals with projects evolving according to a process defined by a series of status transitions. I have a button to set a project to the next status. The button calls a function in the ProjectsController. This function calls another function in the Project model, where I search for the correct transition, depending on the current status, the user_group and some other parameter, and set the new status. After everything successfully accomplished, I return to the original page with '`return $this->redirect($this->referer());`' from the controller.

Some of the transitions have side effects. One is to create a PDF, save it on the server and add a new entry to the 'documents' table referenced to the current project.

Problem: where should I put the function to create the PDF? I would like to put it to the Model. But I need some View Files to first render a html page and then convert it to the PDF. I could put it to the Controller. But then I have a controller function which should not be called directly an doesn't render a view.

The functions all work, but where to put them? Is there another possibility?  Would it be possible to use a component?

Comment: You could create a component and use it from your constructor. There is already an existing component for mpdf if you want to use it: https://github.com/segy/Mpdf

Comment: Implement it as PdfView that will render any (pdf) view for you as Pdf. There is already a plugin that does this, search for CakePdf on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Implement it as PdfView that will render any (pdf) view for you as Pdf. There is already a plugin that does this, search for CakePdf on Github.

A component is clearly the wrong place. A Pdf is output, so it's a kind of view. Model gets you the data, controller sets it, view renders it.

Comment: I already have a view- and a header- (layout-) file that are rendered to a variable in the controller right now. I don't want neither to send the rendered view to the browser nor to download it but save it as a pdf on the server. Wouldn't this be 'application logic' that should go to the model?

Comment: Still use the view to render and fetch the output like you do and then save it to disk. Check how the Email class works for example, AFAIR it gets a new view instance as well to render the email body.